# how to retrieve particular set of information using TopicAPI?

Tags: freebase

I'm a newbie in Freebase Topic API. Currently I am looking for "How to retrieve specific set of data using Freebase Topic API?"

for e.g. if we request for particular information using following URL
https://www.googleapis.com/freebase/v1/topic/en/nicobar_scrubfowl?filter=/common/topic/description

we get ample of information like "id","property","values" array containing "text","lang","value" etc.. And I don't want all the information.

So how to retrieve particular set of information using topicAPI (like only "value" from "values" array OR only "provider" etc..)

thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you want that level of control, you should investigate the MQLRead API.

Comment: Yup, I am going through the MQLRead API

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to filter out those parts of the Topic API response. Every property value will have at least text, lang, id, creator and timestamp.

Why is this a problem in your application? As long as you're parsing this data with a JSON parser you will be able to access any of the data you want while ignoring the rest. If you're worried about the size of the response you can ask for [a GZip response](https://developers.google.com/discovery/v1/performance#gzip).

Comment: Thank you Shawn for the response.
It's been resolved with the help of Newtonsoft.Json parser.